# Как сохранить страницу в .pdf?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

В WF приложении есть браузер (CefSharp). Нужно распечатать страницу сайта в формате .pdf и сохранить его в какую-либо папку на компьютере. Как это сделать?

Например вот эту страницу - https://kad.arbitr.ru/PrintCard/b48828b6-9fce-4eb6-907a-11089efa75d7

Должно получиться что-то такое:

[image: Примерный результат]

Код:

```
   private ChromiumWebBrowser ChromeBrowser;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
        }

   private void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings Settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(Settings);
            ChromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://kad.arbitr.ru/");
            panel1.Controls.Add(ChromeBrowser);
            ChromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
```

Comment: А вы пробовали как-либо? На сколько я вижу, там есть аж [специальный метод](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_PrintToPdf.htm) для этих целей.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну.... Я посмотрел эту документацию, но там же просто написано что есть такие классы, но как их использовать - не написано.

Comment: @aepot Вы не знаете? Это такое формат, типо документа.

Comment: @aepot Исправил....

Comment: Ну.... А я не знаю тогда в чем у вас трудность, чтоб вызвать один [простой метод](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXjZS.png), который требует лишь путь до файла, куда сохранить....

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Что-то не работает. Хоть и выводит слово: "Фортануло"
Код: https://pastebin.com/spJUSn34

Comment: `Async` не смущает? Почитайте про `async/await`, почитайте про `Task`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А поч нельзя вызвать без этого? Такой метод не выдает

Comment: А это уже не ко мне вопрос, а к авторам Cef) В документации как видите есть простой метод. Ну а так, мой коммент выше все еще в силе, читайте про `async/await` и вы поймете как с ним взаимодействовать, поймете, что надо писать `await Метод()`, поймете "костыли", по типу `Метод().Result;` и кучу всего еще полезного.